# Creating a Many to One Class Relationship

Tags: c#

I have a set of class objects that I can not touch. All of them have an ID property that I would like to access in other functions in a generic way.

For simplicities sake here is an example of my problem.

```
class Example1 {
   int ID { get; set;}
}
class Example2 {
   int ID { get; set; }
}
```

I am not able to edit either of these two classes or the library they are in.

I also have a function that expects an ID that can come from either `Example1` or `Example2`. In order to handle this I have come up with a number of solutions but am curious what the proper way to solve this would be.

I could:

1. Use dynamic classes to access the various classes ID's.
2. Use reflection to pull out an ID parameter from any given type.
3. Use an odd inheritance by creating a new class so that `Example1ViewModel : Example1, IIdentifiableObject` and then expect `IIdentifiableObject` in my function and implement a copy constructor in `Example1ViewModel` to handle collecting the data
4. Write a separate filter function that can extract out the relevant parts from either class and provide the results.

None of these solutions seem particularly good to me. How should I be handling a many to one relationship like this in code and are there tools that C# provides to handle this?

Comment: Can you add an extension method to the class Example1 ,Example2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that we ended up using and why.

We are using an inheritence structure that that takes the following two base classes:

```
FooExample
BarExample
```

and wraps them in the following

```
IExample
FooExampleModel : IExample
BarExampleModel : IExample
```

Both `FooExampleModel` and `BarExampleModel` have constructors which accept the class they are wrapping.

The importance of this is that it allows us to create methods accepting IExample instances without having to manipulate data beforehand. Additionally, unlike using dynamic types or reflection this solution provides us with compile time error checking.

Unfortunately using extension methods does not work. While it allows us to call the same method on two different object types like we wanted it does not allow those objects to be passed as Generic types to a seperate function.

The result of all of this is that this is now possible:

```
var foos = new List<FooExample>(); //Pretend there is data here
var bars = new List<BarExample>();
var examples = foos.Select((foo) => (IExample)new FooExampleModel(foo))
                   .Concat(bars.Select((bar) => (IExample)new BarExampleModel(bar)))
                   .ToList(); // Force evaluation before function call
DoSomethingOnIExamples(examples);
```

Besides that slightly gross LINQ query this appears to be the best way to accomplish this (`DoSomethingOnIExamples(...)` is a function accepting an `IEnumerable<IExample>` argument). Obviously this solution gets less nice as more types are added to this mix.

Answer (score 2):

possible solution using extension methods for the classes

```
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int GetId(this Example1 ex)
        {
            return ex.Id;
        }

        public static int GetId(this Example2 ex)
        {
            return ex.Id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but requires some wrapping still. I would need to call these from outside my function and then pass the results in. That's a good solution but do you know a way to limit my function to only accept either `Example1` or `Example2` but not String for example? Or is the wrapper required? I haven't been able to think of a way around something like `examples.Select((ex) => ex.GetId())` before the function.

Comment: I dont think I under stand you quesion .Extension method mean , than now when you create an object ,it has the function . i.e : Example1 ex = new Example(). and you have ex.GetId().

Comment: The goal here seems to be to get things under the same type or allow for some other generic implementation. I am not sure what I gain by adding extension methods unless I can require that they exist somehow. What do I gain from calling GetId() vs simply calling the objects ID property?

Comment: Forcing the existence of the extension method can be done using reflection at a UnitTest level . if you use dynamic and access the ID property there is some performance overhead so that is some thing to take into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a static method using reflection:

```
public static int GetId(object obj)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        return Convert.ToInt32(type.GetProperty("ID").GetValue(obj, null));
    }
```

Then you can invoke it with any object to get the id property value.

Comment: My concern with a reflection or dynamic class solution is that both require runtime based error checking. If possible getting errors at compile time would be ideal.